# Cant get stat of 'var/lib/mysql/ (Errcode:2)

Tags: php, mysql, apache, mysql-loadfile

this code with the path works fine for me in localhost

```
$sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE 'C://xampp/htdocs/xampp/www/tool/".@mysql_escape_string($this->file_name).
         "' INTO TABLE `".$this->table_name.
         "` FIELDS TERMINATED BY '".@mysql_escape_string($this->field_separate_char).
         "' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '".@mysql_escape_string($this->field_enclose_char).
         "' ESCAPED BY '".@mysql_escape_string($this->field_escape_char).
         "' LINES TERMINATED BY '" .@mysql_escape_string("\r\n") . "' ".
         ($this->use_csv_header ? " IGNORE 1 LINES " : "")
         ."(`".implode("`,`", $this->arr_csv_columns)."`)";

        //echo $sql;
          mysqli_query(DB::cxn(),$sql)  or die("Import Error: " . mysqli_error(DB::cxn()));

  // Delete the file now it's been imported
      unlink("C:/xampp/htdocs/xampp/www/tool/". $this->file_name);
```

now when i run in centos server i give path like

```
$sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE 'var/www/html/tool/".@mysql_escape_string($this->file_name).       
  unlink("var/www/html/tool/". $this->file_name);
```

`Cant get stat of 'var/lib/mysql/var/www/html/tool/file.csv (Errcode:2)`

now when i use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` `'var/www/html/tool` it is giving

`cant find file 'var/www/html/file.scv`

my web root folder is in `/var/www/html/tool`   and i access this via `xxx.xxx.xx.xx/tool`

everytime a csv file is uploaded in server location `/var/www/html/tool` with `OWNER as apache-Apache` having `Read and Write`

`Group as apache having only Read Only permisssion`

i tried like chmod 777 -R /var/www/html/tool but the file is still uploading in `apache as group` and `apache-Apache as Owner`

Yes I have seen the other post simillar to this and used `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`
Plz Suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `var/www/html/tool/` as a path and not `/var/www/html/tool/`, thus the path is relative to the mysql directory in `/var/lib/mysql`. Just add another slash at the front.

Comment: that worked man !! csv uploaded in server location but the 1st value from csv file is not showing in browser as it should . i think its a permission issue that case because the group apache has only Read only permission ?

thanks anyway Cheers!!

Comment: Make another question on SO pls with the code, as these are two different questions.

Answer (score 2):

**Just Add `LOCAL` before INFILE in your Query**

`$sql = LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C://xampp/htdocs/xampp/www/tool/"`